# about offset and drift in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neuroscience

I found [this toolbox](https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/mvpa-for-brain-fmri/fmri-data-preprocessing) online.

There is one thing I cannot understand. The toolbox use:

```
X = [ones(numTimeStampPerRun,1) [1:numTimeStampPerRun]']; % account for both offset and drift
```

to account for both offset and drift. I cannot understand what "offset" and "drift" represent in fMRI signal? Why the toolbox use this format to account for both offset and drift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that they are detrending the signal by regressing out x. In this case `ones` part is the offset, and `1: numTimeStampPerRun` is the linear trend.

You can always just use [`detrend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detrend.html) in MATLAB though.

EDIT: more explicitly, the linear fit has the form:

x(t) = a*t + b*1

where `t = 1:numTimeStampPerRun`.

Comment: yes, you are right. but the part I do not understand is: why ones part is the offset, and  1:numTimeStampPerRun is the linear trend? How do we know?

Comment: I still cannot understand why the author define "offset" by using ones(numTimeStampPerRun,1) and define "drift" by using [1:numTimeStampPerRun]'.  In you explanation, "b" is the offset? and "a*t" is the drift? Then what is the value of "a"?

Comment: @Angelababy yes, a is the drift, and b is the offset. You are inferring both a and b from data. I suggest you look into linear regression.